# Jhipster4 not building angular 2 app

Tags: java, angular, web, jhipster

I used jhipster4 to generate my application. The application has a client side and a server side. When I `./mvnw` from the app root directory, it only builds the server, but not the client. Here's my project root.

[image: Project Root]

The directory "target" contains the build. The angular app would be in a directory named "www", but as you can see below it isn't there.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command `yarn start` from the project root. That fixed it.

Comment: Yes that's the expected workflow, https://jhipster.github.io/development/#working-with-angular